# What would be a good way to work with a large data set in Excel?

Tags: excel, large-data

I have a large data set which is in .dbf format right now and what I would like to do is be able to manipulate it easily in Excel and do something like subtotal and calculate stdev and ratios.

Details of the data set;
This data set contains shopper information. It has 1.2 million rows and 20 columns where the rows are each a unique shopper and the columns hold their shopping data (what they bought).

I am using Office 2007 programs, I know Excel the best but was wondering what alternatives I could use to accomplish my goals (subtotal, calculate stdev, and ratio's).

Comment: As far as I know, Excel 2007 only allows you to have 1 million or so rows (A quick google search turns up a maximum of 1,048,576 rows in Excel 2007). I would say your best bet is to use a database program, like SQL or Access. There are simple database queries that will give you what you want (subtotals, sd's, etc). Also, I haven't really worked with it myself, but I am sure you can access datasets from Access using Excel. Honestly, though, I would just use R, and for what you're trying to calculate, it does not take long to learn some simple functions :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about R, do you know any online resources that could get me up and running fairly quickly?  I have some experience programming in Python.

Comment: @Furlong: You can download R for free [here](http://www.r-project.org/). There are many guides to get started with R available online. Here is [one for beginners](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf) that I found on google. Since you have experience in a programming language, you should be fine with the idea of variable assignment. You should focus on reading in files in R, and learning how to use functions (like sum(), mean(), sd(), etc).

Comment: If your original file is in the Access format, you can calculate what you need with the help of quires and/or Visual Basic modules.

Comment: If you already know Python this task is trivial and there is no need to download R. There is the dbfpy package for reading dbf files directly, xlrd for reading Excel files, and numpy has the summary statistics.

Comment: @Josh, xlrd works only with xls, Excel 2007 uses xlsx. You can convert but it might get tedious. And probably xlwt will be more needed here to write to Excel files, not to read.

Comment: @mpiktas - You are right; thank you for the correction! I should know better too. I have read Excel 2007 files with win32com, and then there are the openpyxl and pyxlsx packages. This blog shows a ton of stuff you can do to programmatically read/write Excel files from Python (e.g., programmatically writing pivot tables): http://www.pythonexcels.com/

Answer (score 15):

If you feel you may start more of such very large Excel type projects in the future, then you should consider installing and spending 10 hours learning the basics of R (free), which will let you do what you mention in your question, in a much more efficient manner than Excel.
[R for Beginners PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf)

You can ask questions about R on [StackOverflow](http://stackexchange.com/) and here.

Answer (score 10):

Although I would always recommend to use R, you could nevertheless achieve what you want with python.

There is at least a package for reading [dbf files](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf/).

Furthermore, [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) offers a great range of functions for statistical analysis. For example the library [ScientifyPython](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/plone/software/scientificpython/) probably contains [the functions](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/ScientificPython/ScientificPythonManual/toc-Scientific.Statistics-module.html) you need.

The best idea is to check [scipy.org](http://www.scipy.org/). There you will find what you want.

(But learning R is a great idea!!)

Comment: +1 for giving someone direction in a language they already know. Note that numpy has all of the functionality the OP has described needing.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2010 and 2013 have a free microsoft addin called  [power pivot](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel/download-power-pivot-HA101959985.aspx) which allows you to work with millions of rows. Its a columnar database that is designed for creating pivot tables, subtotals etc and has standard deviation etc predefined. you might also look at other microsoft addins power query (data input), power view (visualisation), and power map (mapping)